# Error al modificar elementos en sublistas, todas terminan con el mismo contenido

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alguien podría decirme por qué tengo error en el siguiente código:

```
tabla=[]
linea=['0']
for k in range (3):
    linea.append('')
for k in range(12):
    tabla.append(linea)
i=0
for k in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','E','F','P','G','2G','T']:
    tabla[i][0] = k
    i+=1
print(tabla)
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

```
[['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', ''],
 ['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', ''],
 ['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', ''],
 ['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', '']
```

en lugar del que busco que es:

```
[['1', '', '', ''], ['2', '', '', ''], ['3', '', '', ''],
 ['4', '', '', ''], ['5', '', '', ''], ['6', '', '', ''],
 ['E', '', '', ''], ['F', '', '', ''], ['P', '', '', ''],
 ['G', '', '', ''], ['2G', '', '', ''], ['T', '', '', '']
```

Como se puede ver, todas las sublistas contienen "T" como primer elemento, en vez de contener el valor correspondiente asignado en el `for` con `tabla[i][0] = k`. ¿Qué hago mal?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Luis. Como eres nuevo por aquí te comento unas cosillas. El  apartado de respuestas solo puede ser usado para agregar respuestas a la pregunta, si necesitas pedir aclaraciones usa los comentarios como este. Si necesitas agregar o modificar información de tu pregunta usa el botón `editar` que hay debajo de la pregunta. Deberías eliminar ambas "respuestas" para que no sean eliminadas vía colas de revisión y eventualmente te den votos negativos.

Comment: Por otro lado, cuando copies código lo seleccionaa todo y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor, de esta forma queda formateado como código y no queda todo desestructurado.  Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Python generalizando todo son objetos. Una lista en esencia solo es una colección ordenada que almacena **referencias a objetos en memoria**, por eso puedes meter en una lista cualquier cosa, desde otra lista a una función.

Cuando haces `tabla.append(linea)` lo que en realidad haces es añadir una nueva referencia al objeto `linea` a la lista `tabla`. Por lo tanto, en el ciclo te limitas a **añadir referencias al mismo objeto (`linea`) a tu lista tabla**.

Resumiendo, todas las sublistas que contiene tu lista `tabla` son en realidad la misma lista, tienen la misma referencia. Cuando modificas un valor en una el resto también se modifican ya que son en realidad el mismo objeto. Cuando termina tu ciclo asignas el valor "T" al primer elemento de la última "línea", como en realidad todas las líneas son la misma lista se refleja en todas.

La solución es simplemente agregar una copia de tu lista `línea` cada vez que agregues una a la matriz:

```
tabla.append(linea[:])
```

Se usa *slicing* o rebanado de listas para retornar una `shallow copy` de la lista original. De esta forma cada sublista de `tabla` es un objeto distinto, una lista distinta. Es equivalente a:

```
import copy

tabla.append(copy.copy(linea))
```

Hay que tener en cuenta el concepto de *shadow copy* o "copia superficial". En este tipo de copias se copia el objeto en si, la lista, pero no los objetos que ésta contiene. En tu caso **la lista `fila` se copia pero su contenido no se copia, se usan las mismas referencias.** Como parece que solo contiene objetos inmutables (cadenas) no hay problema. Esto se debe a que "modificar" un objeto inmutable implica crear un nuevo objeto.

Esto no pasa si fueran objetos mutables, en este caso debes usar una *deep copy* o "copia en profundidad", de forma que tanto la lista como todos los objetos que contiene son copiados recursivamente:

```
import copy

tabla.append(copy.deepcopy(linea))
```

---

Una alternativa para hacer lo que quieres es usar listas por compresión:

```
tabla = [[elem] + ["" for _ in range(3)]
            for elem in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'E', 'F', 'P', 'G', '2G', 'T']]
```

---

### **Edición**

Por si interesa se puede ver el los comportamientos descritos arriba en detalle con un ejemplo:

```
>>> lista1 = [1,  "a",  (1,  2),  ["c"]]
>>> lista2 = lista1
```

Hacer `lista2 = lista1` no copia `lista1`, simplemente asigna la referencia al objeto asociado a `lista1`  a la variable `lista2`. Esto hace que ambos identificadores apuntan a la misma lista, al mismo objeto en memoria. Lo podemos ver usando el builtin `id`:

```
>>> id(lista1)
140001243246088
>>> id(lista2)
140001243246088
```

Modificar una implica modificar la otra (ambas son las mismas en realidad):

```
>>> lista1[0] = 147
>>> lista1
[147, 'a', (1, 2), ['c']]
>>> lista2
[147, 'a', (1, 2), ['c']]
```

Ahora vamos a ver que es una *shallow copy* o copia superficial:

```
>>> lista2 = lista1[:] # equivalente a lista2 = copy.copy(lista1)
```

En este caso `lista1` y `lista2` son dos objetos distintos:

```
>>> id(lista1)
140001243246088
>>> id(lista2)
140001243245192
```

pero no los elementos que contienen:

```
>>> id(lista1[0])
140001273510848
>>> id(lista2[0])
140001273510848
```

Si "modificamos" un elemento inmutable el cambio solo se refleja en la lista que se aplica, ya que implica la creación de un nuevo objeto. Si modificamos un objeto mutable como una lista el cambio se refleja en ambas listas:

```
>>> lista1[0] += 777
>>> lista1[3].append("Hola") 
>>> lista1
[924, 'a', (1, 2), ['c', 'Hola']]
>>> lista2
[147, 'a', (1, 2), ['c', 'Hola']]
```

Para que los objetos mutables sean objetos distintos necesitamos una copia profunda como se comentó:

```
>>> import copy
>>> lista2 = copy.deepcopy(lista1)
>>> lista1
[777, 'a', (1, 2), ['c', 'Hola']]
>>> lista2
[777, 'a', (1, 2), ['c', 'Hola']]
>>> lista1[3].append("Mundo")
>>> lista1
[777, 'a', (1, 2), ['c', 'Hola', 'Mundo']]
>>> lista2
[777, 'a', (1, 2), ['c', 'Hola']]
```