# ¿por que se actualiza una variable cuando hago operaciones en otra que fue asignado de esa variable? pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

tengo este problema nose si es algo de la librería pygame

**posInicial** Actualiza cuando modifico el array **movimientoCola**

lo que averigüe del problema es que **posInicial** lo asigno a cada fila de el array
entonces al momento de modificar un solo elemento el valor nuevo se asigna a **posInicial** y modifica todo el array(**movimientoCola** ) y todas las filas tienen el mismo valor pido ayuda porque esta pasando esto.

```
#variables Globales
posInicial = [10, 400]
movimientoCola = [[posInicial, 0] for _ in range(4)]

def mover_Usuario():
"""MoverUsuario."""
for i in range(len(movimientoCola)):
    if movimientoCola[i][1]:
        movimientoCola[i][0] = atender_Usuario(movimientoCola[i][0], i)
        if type(movimientoCola[i][0]) == int:
            print("llego ", i)
            movimientoCola[i][1] = 0
            movimientoCola[i][0] = [10, 400]
    crear_Usuario(movimientoCola[i][0])
```

resultados.
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A cuales variables te refieres, tu descripcion es muy confusa.

Comment: posInicial Actualiza cuando modifico el array movimientoCola en ningun momento le asigno un nuevo valor a posInicial

Comment: Luis si te he entendido bien tu problema es similar al  mostrado  en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105431/15089. El objeto `posInicial` es es mismo en todas las sublistas. Modificar cualquiera de ellas o la misma variable global `posInicial` implica modificarlos todos porque son el mismo objeto. Cuando haces `[posInicial, 0]` simplemente haces que el primer elemento de la lista sea la **referencia** al objeto `posInicial`, no estas realizando una copia en ningún momento.

Comment: si era eso no se porque no me a pasado antes si muchas veces lo echo asi.

Comment: Luis es un comportamiento esperado al ser pasado todo por referencia y que hay que tener en cuenta para evitar este tipo de bugs. Al final de la respuesta que doy a esa pregunta hay una explicación con ejemplos de este comportamiento.Es fundamental tener en cuenta la mutabilidad o no de los objetos que contiene la lista.En tu caso al ser enteros (inmutables) basta con que usas slicing:  `movimientoCola = [[posInicial[:], 0] for _ in range(4)]`. En cambio, si tu lista contuviera listas (mutables) y no int `posInicial[:]` no serviría,parece un lio pero una vez que lo entiendes es bastante simple