# ¿Por que los atributos privados de una clase se cambian apesar de asignarlos a otra variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase, atributos

Se define una clase con un atributo 'privado' llamado `__rango` luego se desea hacer una copia de este atributo en la variable `rangoT` para modificarlo sin afectar al atributo original, pero los dos cambian su valor.

Definición de la clase:

```
class Nivel():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__rango = []

    def setRango(self, rango=[]):
        self.__rango = rango

    def getRango(self):
        return self.__rango

    def jugarCopiaRango(self):
        rangoT = []
        rangoT = self.getRango()
        rangoT[0] = 100
        print('la copia del rango luego de la modificación')
        print(rangoT)
```

Creamos la instancia de la clase y utilizamos los métodos:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = Nivel()
    n.setRango([12, 11, 14, 15])
    print('el rango original')
    print(n.getRango())
    n.jugarCopiaRango()
    print('el rango original no debería cambiar pero:')
    print(n.getRango())
```

El resultado es:

> el rango original
>   [12, 11, 14, 15]
>   la copia del rango luego de la modificación
>   [100, 11, 14, 15]
>   el rango original no debería cambiar pero:
>   [100, 11, 14, 15]

¿Que se debe hacer para no modificar al atributo privado `__rango` cuando se modifica a `rangoT`. Se usa Python 3.6.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos a ir por partes, primero **los atributos o métodos privados estrictamente no existen en Python** como creo que ya sabes dado que entrecomillas lo de "privado". El uso del doble underscore al inicio del identificador para este fin es un error/malentendido histórico que se ha extendido creando confusión, sobretodo porque los programadores tienden a intentar usar este mecanismo para definir atributos privados al estilo de lenguajes como C++ o Java, lo cual es un error porque jamás se pensó para este fin.

A este mecanismo se le conoce como ***name mangling***. Cuando cualquier identificador se le antepone un doble subrayado (sin doble subrayado al final) se reemplaza automáticamente por `_nombreDeLaClase__identificador`.

La idea es evitar conflictos entre los identificadores de las clases y por ejemplo evitar posibles sobreescrituras no deseadas de forma accidental en la herencia:

```
class A:
    def __bar(self):  # Método "privado"
        print("Soy el método bar de la clase A")

    def bar(self):    # Método "público"
        self.__bar()

class B(A):
    def __bar(self):
        print("Soy el método bar de la clase B")

>>> b = B()
>>> b.bar()
>>> Soy el método bar de la clase A
```

Podemos ver como el `__bar` de `B` no sobreescribe al `__bar` de su clase padre porque los métodos pasaron a llamarse `_A__bar` y `_B__bar` respectivamente. ciertamente que esto puede dar la sensación de que se trata de un método "privado" porque:

```
>>> b.__bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    b.__bar()
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '__bar'
```

Pero repito, nos son atributos/métodos privados (entendiendo como tal que no son accesibles de ninguna forma desde fuera de la clase), este no es su uso y no deben usarse para esto.  No es un método privado, simplemte `__bar` no es su nombre,  cualquiera puede acceder a el mediante:

```
>>> b._B__bar()
Soy el método bar de la clase B
```

Python, aunque esto choque y muchos lo odien por esto, no tiene como filosofía poner restricciones al programador, se presupone que ya es "mayor de edad" y es consciente de lo que hace. Efectivamente hay casos en los que un método/atributo no debe ser modificado desde fuera de su clase, para estos casos la convención es indicar que una variable o método es privado mediante **un solo underscore** (sin menoscabo de que se explicite en la documentación). Sigue siendo un identificador igual que otro, es solo una marca para indicar a los desarrolladores que deben tratarlo como privado y que el acceso a el directamente puede implicar riesgos.

Por último, hay que tener en cuenta que el proceso de mangling **se lleva a cabo durante la definición de la clase**, es decir, si hacemos:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__bar = 4

inst = Foo()
inst.__bar = 7
```

En `inst.__bar = 7` el interprete busca el atributo `__bar` entre los atributos de instancia y de clase, como no lo encuentra debido a que el atributo creado con `self.__bar` es renombrado a `_Foo.__bar`, se procede como con cualquier asignación, **se crea un nuevo atributo de instancia** llamado `__bar` y se le asigna la referencia al 7. Pero hay que recordar que en este caso no se aplica el name mangling para este atributo ya que se crea posteriormente a la definición de la clase. Podemos verlo mas claro mostrando los atributos de instancia:

```
>>> inst.__dict__
{'_Foo__bar': 4, '__bar': 7}
```

---

Teniendo esto claro, no debemos confundir el concepto de "privado" con el de "mutabilidad". `self.__rango` es una **lista** y por tanto un **objeto mutable**, cuando haces:

```
rangoT = self.getRango()
```

**estás asignando la referencia** (dirección de memoria) de `self.__rango` a `rangoT` **no creando una copia de la misma**, es decir ambos identificadores apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria. Como las listas son mutables, cuando intentas modificar el objeto mediante una de las variables, no se crea un nuevo objeto, simplemente se modifica. Al apuntar ambas variables al mismo objeto, ambas muestran el cambio. La siguiente pregunta tiene como base el mismo error:

[Error al modificar elementos en sublistas, todas terminan con el mismo contenido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105431/15089)

Dicho esto, el concepto de setter y getter en Python tampoco existen como tales, en su lugar la forma "pitónica" es usar *properties*, con todo esto tu código podría ser:

```
class Nivel:
    def __init__(self):
        self._rango = []  # Atributo de instancia "privado"

    # "getter"
    @property
    def rango(self):
        return self._rango.copy()  # Retornamos una copia del atributo "privado"

    # "setter"
    @rango.setter
    def rango(self, rango=[]):
        self._rango = rango.copy()

    def jugar_copia_rango(self):
        rango_t = self.rango
        rango_t[0] = 100
        print('la copia del rango luego de la modificación')
        print(rango_t)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = Nivel()
    n.rango = [12, 11, 14, 15]
    print('El rango original:')
    print(n.rango)
    n.jugar_copia_rango()
    print('El rango original no cambia:')
    print(n.rango)
```

En este caso, el "getter" de self._range retorna siempre una copia del mismo. Es decir, cuando haces `b.range` o `self.range` obtienes la referencia de una copia de `self._range` y no la referencia al objeto en sí mismo.

> **Nota:** Lo que obtenemos es lo que se conoce como *shallow copy*, es decir se copia el objeto (la lista) pero los elemento que contienen no son copiados y son compartidos entre ambas listas. En este caso almacenas enteros, que son inmutables, pero si tu atributo `self._range` es susceptible de contener elementos mutables debes usar una "copia muerta" para que también sus elementos sean copiados. esto se hace mediante [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me has enviado a investigar pensé que python era como dicen un lenguaje que "hace hincapié en una sintaxis que favorezca un código legible". Para los nuevos como yo que deseen saber más sobre las propierties y decoradores tal vez les sirva este enlace en inglés https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada, una aclaración: en Python no existen atributos privados, ni mucho menos protegidos. Dicho esto el problema lo tienes aquí:

```
def jugarCopiaRango(self):
    rangoT = []
    rangoT = self.getRango() # <---
```

Seguramente estás pensando que `self.getRango()` está devolviendo una "copia" de la lista original `self.__rango` cuando en realidad lo que está haciendo al tratarse de una lista, es retornar la referencia a `self.__rango` sobreescribiendo el valor inicial que le  habías dado. Por lo que al hacer:

```
rangoT[0] = 100
```

en realidad estás haciendo:

```
self.__rango[0] = 100
```

y teniendo en cuenta lo primero que comenté con respecto a los atributos, claramente estás modificando el valor original. Si quieres evitar esto una opción sería:

```
def getRango(self):
    return list(self.__rango)
```

Al usar `list()` estás creando una "copia" de la variable de la clase, en este caso la actualización posterior no impactará sobre el atributo original.