# Error en encapsulamiento de clase

Tags: python

Mi error es este, cuando ejecuto el programa luego de encapsular la clase **self.ruedas=4**, al momento de compilar ***Pycharm*** me da el siguiente error:

> AttributeError: 'Coche' object has no attribute 'ruedas'

Código:

```
class Coche():
    # Hagamos un constructor por defecto para toda la clase
    def __init__(self):
        # Establescamos las propiedades del objeto coche
        self.largoChasis = 250
        self.anchochasis = 120
        # encapsulemos la variable para que no pueda ser modificada desde afuera de la clase
        self.__ruedas = 4
        self.enmarcha = False

    # Establescamos el comportamiento con metodos
    def arrancar(self, arrancamos):
        self.enmarcha = arrancamos

        if (self.enmarcha):
            return "El coche esta en marcha"
        else:
            return "El coche esta parado"

    def estado(self):
        print("El tiene ", self.__ruedas, "Ruedas. Un ancho de", self.anchochasis, "y un largo de", self.largoChasis)


# creemos un objeto o instancia:
miCoche = Coche()
# Preguntemos por sus propiedades
print("Largo:", miCoche.largoChasis)
print("El coche tiene", miCoche.ruedas, "ruedas")
# preguntemos por el comportamiento
print(miCoche.arrancar(True))
miCoche.estado()

print("----------A continuacion creamos el segundo objeto----------")

miCoche2 = Coche()
print("Largo:", miCoche2.largoChasis)
print("El coche tiene", miCoche2.ruedas, "ruedas")
print(miCoche2.arrancar(False))
miCoche2.estado()
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que esperas, aclarar que anteponiendo `__`  **no haces un atributo privado**, ese concepto no existe en Python. A eso se le conoce como "name mangling" y su objetivo no es hacer privado un atributo (aunque históricamente se crea eso es un error de concepto importante) pero si "oculta" el atributo (aunque se puede seguir modificando desde fuera si se sabe como hacer referencia a él). El problema es que intentas acceder al atributo como si no usaras ese mecanismo, `miCoche2.ruedas`. Mirate https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/154715/15089

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si encapsulas la variable __ruedas dentro del objeto luego no puedes acceder a él directamente desde fuera, ni para cambiarlo ni para leerlo.

En ese caso tendrias que hacer mencion al objeto del que viene, en este caso "Coche" tal que así:

```
print("El coche tiene", miCoche._Coche__ruedas, "ruedas")
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, en el curso que estoy viendo no explicaron eso