# Me da error al crear el setter con PyCharm Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

El ejemplo lo saqué de uno en Python 2, pero al hacerlo en Python 3.7 me da el siguiente error:

File "D:/python/ejercicios pycharm/POO/StudentClass.py", line 30
    return self.nombre=nuevoNombre
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

En el video que usé ejemplo lo hacia de esta forma pero yo intento y no me da, la verdad ya miré en todos lados y nose como sacar ese error. 
Me marca el error don dice nuevoNombre, nuevoTelefono, nuevaEdad y nuevoPeso. Supongo que no se pone de esa forma. También probé hacerlo con "property y tampoco pude. 
La idea del programa es que se ingresen los datos de los estudiantes y luego puedan ser modificados.

```
class StudentClass:

 matricula=""
 nombre=""
 telefono=""
 edad=0
 peso=0.0

 def __init__(self, matricula, nombre):

    self.matricula=matricula
    self.nombre=nombre

 def getMatricula(self):
   return self.matricula

 def getNombre(self):
   return self.nombre

 def getTelefono(self):
   return self.telefono

 def getEdad(self):
   return self.edad

 def getPeso(self):
   return self.peso

 def setNombre(self, nuevoNombre):
   return self.nombre=nuevoNombre

 def setTelefono(self, nuevoTelefono):
   return self.telefono=nuevoTelefono

 def setEdad(self, nuevoEdad):
   return self.edad=nuevoEdad

 def setPeso(self, nuevoPeso):
   return self.peso=nuevoPeso

estudiante=None

while True:
  print("\n\n MENU \n")
  print("1- AGREGAR ESTUDIANTE")
  print("2- MODIFICAR DATOS")
  print("3- VER DATOS DEL ESTUDIANTE")
  print("4- SALIR")
  opcion = input("Selecciona una opcion:")

  if opcion == "1":
    print("Escribe los datos basico del estudiante (no se podran modificar)")
    matricula = input("Matricula: ")
    nombre = input("Escribe el nombre: ")
    estudiante = StudentClass(matricula, nombre)

  elif opcion == "2":
    while True:
        print("\n\n MENU PARA MODIFICAR \n")
        print("1- ACTUALIZAR TELEFONO")
        print("2- ACTUALIZAR EDAD")
        print("3- ACTUALIZAR PESO")
        print("4- REGERESAR A MENU ANTERIOR")
        opcion2= input("Selecciona una opcion:")

        if opcion2 == "1":
            telefono = input("Telefono: ")
            estudiante.setTelefono(telefono)
        elif opcion2 == "2":
            edad = input("Edad: ")
            estudiante.setEdad(edad)
        elif opcion2 == "3":
            peso = input("Edad: ")
            estudiante.setPeso(peso)
        elif opcion2 == "4":
            break

  elif opcion == "3":
    print("\n\n DATOS DEL ESTUDIANTE \n")
    print("MATRICULA: " + estudiante.getMatricula())
    print("NOMBRE: " + estudiante.getNombre())
    print("TELEFONO: " + estudiante.getTelefono())
    print("EDAD: " + str(estudiante.getEdad()))
    print("PESO: " + str(estudiante.getPeso()))

  elif opcion == "4":
    print("Adios")
    break

  else:
    print("Opcion no valida")
```

Comment: En principio es un error tipográfico más que nada. El problema es que tratas de retornar el resultado de una asignación. (`return self.nombre=nuevoNombre`). Si el método se va a comportar como un setter (aunque [este concepto no existe en Python como tal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/154758/15089) al estilo de otros lenguajes como C++ ni se considera pitónico su uso, lo más aproximado son las propiedades) no debería retornar nada, bastaría con la asignación `self.nombre=nuevoNombre`. Lo mismo para los otros.

Comment: Por cierto, [deberías definir los atributos dentro del `__init__` (atributos de instancia, lo que son realmente)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089) no debajo de la declaración de la clase (atributos de clase, compartidos por todas las instancias de la misma)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Arreglé lo del return y ahora si funciona. Voy a probar hacer la modificación de los atributos también. Muy agradecida del consejo.