# Encapsulamiento de clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código el cual debe encapsular los atributos x e y. Además debe asegúrarse de que esas propiedades solo aceptan valores de tipo int o float, de forma que, si se intenta asignar un valor de otro tipo, a alguna de las propiedades, se lance la excepción TypeError, con el mensaje "El tipo de x no es el que se esperaba"  o "el tipo de y no es el que se esperaba", según sea el caso. **Tenía pensado implementarlo con un decorador property @property pero no se como se construye** **El output es el esperado pero no se si es correcto**

```
class Punto:
    """Clase Punto"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Punto con sus respectivas coordenadas"""
        self.x = x      
        self.y = y      

    def get_value(self):
        if type(self.__x) != int and type(self.__x) != float:
            raise ("el tipo de x no es el que se esperaba")
        return (self.__x, self.__y)

         if type(self.__y) != int and type(self.__y) != float:
            raise ("el tipo de y no es el que se esperaba")
        return (self.__x, self.__y)

    def set_value(self, new_value):
        self.__value = new_value if type(new_value) == int or type(new_value) == float else 0


    value = property(get_value)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Punto(-8.7, 2.5)
    print("(x = {}, y = {})".format(p.x, p.y))
```

> OUTPUT: (x = -8.7, y = 2.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- En el "getter" no deberías validar los valores, simplemente debería limitarse a acceder a los atributos "privados" y retornar su valor. La validación  debes hacerla en el "setter".
- Actualmente instanciar tu clase con (por ejemplo):

  ```
  p = Punto("hola", 2.5)
  ```

  es válido, cuando no debería serlo. El problema es que no usas el "setter" en ningún momento para validar los argumentos pasados al inicializador o para validar la asignación mediante referencia al atributo directamente (p.ej `p.x = 8`.

Ante todo, aclarar que el encapsulamiento en Python, tal como se enetiende en otros lenguajes, no existe. Los atributos son públicos y no hay forma de hacerlos verdaderamente privados. Por convención se usa _ antes del identificador de un atributo/método para avisar que debe ser considerado privado y no debe modificarse o leerse directamente. El uso de `__` antes de un atributo o método tampoco hace el atributo privado, es solo para evitar conflictos ente identificadores, especialmente en casos de herencia:

- [¿Por que los atributos privados de una clase se cambian apesar de asignarlos a otra variable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/154715/15089)

Ninguno de los dos mecanismos, ni tampoco el uso de propiedades evita realmente (si verdaderamente queremos) que se pueda acceder a los atributos supuestamente privados. Python por filosofía tiende a tratar al programador como "mayor de edad", en vez de prohibir que se pueda acceder a los atributos la idea es avisar de que deberían tratarse como privados, pero una vez avisado, si se quiere acceder a ellos se es libre de hacerlo, se supone que sabemos lo que hacemos... :). Por esta misma razón el uso de setter y getter tal como se entienden en otros lenguajes como C++ no existe en Python.

Por lo tanto, en Python la forma normal y "pitónica" de acceder a los atributos es simplemente, acceder a los atributos directamente. Ahora bien, si necesitas realmente algo similar, lo apropiado generalmente es usar propidades, una ventaja de las propiedades es que se accede a ellas de forma idéntica a los atributos, permitiendo agregar funcionalidad extra y modificarla más adelante o eliminarla  sin modificar la forma en que se llama, además es más intuitivo.

Volviendo a tu código, si deseas usar el decorador `@property`, puedes hacer algo así:

```
class Punto:
    """Clase Punto"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Punto con sus respectivas coordenadas"""
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self.x = x      
        self.y = y

    class Punto:
        """Clase Punto"""
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            """Punto con sus respectivas coordenadas"""
            self.x = x      
            self.y = y      

        @property
        def x(self):
           return self._x

        @x.setter
        def x(self, new_value):
            if isinstance(new_value, float) or isinstance(new_value, int):
                self._x = new_value
            else:
                raise ValueError("x debe ser int o float")

        @property
        def y(self):
            return self._y

        @y.setter
        def y(self, new_value):
            if isinstance(new_value, float) or isinstance(new_value, int):
                self._y = new_value
            else:
                raise ValueError("y debe ser int o float")


    if __name__ == "__main__":

        p = Punto(3.5, 2.5)
        print("(x = {}, y = {})".format(p.x, p.y))
```

Que sería equivalente a, usando el built-in `property()`:

```
class Punto:
    """Clase Punto"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Punto con sus respectivas coordenadas"""
        self._x = None
        self._y = None
        self.x = x      
        self.y = y  


    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, new_value):
        if isinstance(new_value, float) or isinstance(new_value, int):
            self._x = new_value
        else:
            raise ValueError("x debe ser int o float")

    def gety(self):
        return self._y

    def sety(self, new_value):
        if isinstance(new_value, float) or isinstance(new_value, int):
            self._y = new_value
        else:
            raise ValueError("y debe ser int o float")

    x = property(fget=getx, fset=setx)
    y = property(fget=gety, fset=sety)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Punto(3.5, 2.5)
    print("(x = {}, y = {})".format(p.x, p.y))
```

En ambos casos si intentas instanciar la clase pasando argumentos que no sean `int` o `float` (y clases derivadas) tienes una excepción:

> ```
> >>> p = Punto("hola", 2.5)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/main.py", line 35, in <module>
>     p = Punto("hola", 2.5)
>   File "main.py", line 7, in __init__
>     self.x = x      
>   File "main.py", line 18, in setx
>     raise ValueError("x debe ser int o float")
> ValueError: x debe ser int o float
> ```

igual que si se intenta asignar directamente un valor no válido aa los atributos (propiedades):

> ```
> >>> p = Punto("hola", 2.5)
> >>> p.y = "hola" 
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "main.py", line 27, in sety
>     raise ValueError("y debe ser int o float")
> ValueError: y debe ser int o float
> ```

Todo esto está íntimamente relacionado con el llamado "[protocolo descriptor"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) que en esencia es la  solapar un atributo con un objeto que hace de intermediario a la hora de acceder a él. Las propiedades son un ejemplo muy claro de descriptores.