# ayuda con la función shuffle en python

Tags: python, arraylist, random

Quiero hacer un array con varias listas de objetos y quiero que sean diferentes, por eso uso la función `shuffle`:

```
import random

class ciudad:
    def __init__(self,nombre,comp_x,comp_y):
        self.x = comp_x
        self.y = comp_y
        self.nombre = nombre


#Definimos las ciudades y sus componentes
c2 = ciudad("c2",5,4)
c3 = ciudad("c3",7,4)
c4 = ciudad("c4",5,6)
vectores=\[\]
numero_vectores = 0 
base = \[c2,c3,c4\]
while numero_vectores < 6:
    random.shuffle(base)
    print("vector base desordenado:", numero_vectores)
    for ciudad in aux:
        print(ciudad.nombre)
    vectores.append(aux)
    numero_vectores += 1
for vector in vectores:#Intento verificar que se hayan agregado bien
    print("Inicio vector")
    for ciudad in vector:
        print(ciudad.nombre)
```

En el primer `while` me muestra que los valores de la variable base si cambia y los agrego a la lista, pero después del `while` cuando verifico el contenido del array "vectores", me aparecen las 6 listas pero todas son iguales, iguales al ultimo valor que tuvo la variable base, es decir se quedan con el valor del ultimo `shuffle`, les agradecería mucho si me pueden explicar que está pasando y como lo puedo solucionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Fernando, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Dónde defines `aux`? Presiento que el problema es este: [Error al modificar elementos en sublistas, todas terminan con el mismo contenido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105431/error-al-modificar-elementos-en-sublistas-todas-terminan-con-el-mismo-contenido)

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Después de investigar un poco me di cuenta que si igualas dos arrays en python "A=B" y modificas B, el cambio también le afecta a "A", entonces lo que se tiene que hacer es una "copia" del array por ejemplo: A = B[:], de esta manera A toma el valor que tenia B a la hora de la asignación, en caso de que B sea modificado, A no se verá afectado.
En mi caso lo arreglé añadiendo esta línea:
    vectores.append(aux[:])