# Problemas para agregar elementos a una lista en python

Tags: python, parser

estoy programando algunas cosas en Python, específicamente una función parser que llama a otra función que retorna las líneas de un archivo, luego, por cada línea se hace un split para separarlas en dos campos, dichos campos se almacenan en un diccionario, luego ese ítem de diccionario se va a una lista. El problema que tengo es la lista se llena solamente con el diccionario de la última línea del archivo, diciendo que las lineas si están entrando una a una y si se está generando su respectivo ítem de diccionario. Les dejo el código de la función.

```
`def parserDownloads(FILE_PATH):
list_filenames=[]
file_url={}
lines=readIpFile(FILE_PATH)
count=0
aux={}
while count<len(lines):
    fields=lines[count].split("\t")
    file_url["filename"]=fields[0]
    file_url["url"]=fields[1]
    print lines[count]
    print file_url
    list_filenames.append(file_url)
    count=count+1

print list_filenames
return list_filenames`
```

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Pablo te recomiendo mirarte [tour] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio. Debes agregar el código en la pregunta directamente, no uses enlaces externos que pueden caer en el futuro y dejar la pregunta sin sentido, además de dificultar la lectura y las búsquedas. Para formatear el código solo tienes que copiarlo, seleccionarlo y pulsar `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor.

Comment: No hay "un diccionario de la última línea" `list_filenames.append(file_url)` añade el diccionario a la lista en cada iteración pero no hace ninguna copia del mismo, todos los items de la lista apuntan al mismo diccionario, todos los items son el mismo objeto `file_url`, por lo que cuando se modifica en el último ciclo el cambio se refleja en todos (porque todos son el mismo diccionario). O creas una copia del diccionario en cada iteración del ciclo o inicializas el diccionario dentro del `while` en vez de fuera.  Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/105431/15089.

Comment: Listo ya lo solucioné, hice algo muy parecido a lo que dicen arriba.

Comment: @PabloOlivares recomiendo que agregues la forma en como lo solucionó, recuerda que esta es una comunidad que provee ayuda, es una buena practica para futuros visitantes encontrar la respuesta a la pregunta aun cuando usted mismo la haya provisto

Comment: Lo hice según lo que dijo @FJSevilla... Saludos!