# ¿Cómo sobreescribir una variable donde se almacenaron las líneas de un archivo txt?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando extraer información especifica de un archivo.txt, para esto aplico los metodos para leer el archivo y almacenar en una variable las lineas del mismo, una vez consigo obtener los datos, separo los elementos de cada linea (buscando obtener una matriz).

Este proceso funciona a la perfección, pero luego de esto necesito solo extraer la información realmente importante para mi, que serían los elementos de las columnas 2, 3 y 9 de la matriz anteriormente conseguida, sin embargo, cuando trato de sobreescribir esta información solo me llena la 'matriz_resumen' con el último dato del array.

```
ruta = "Archivos_txt\Esfuerzos.txt"

with open(ruta) as archivo:
    
    linea = archivo.readlines()
    
    Num_lineas = len(linea)  
    
    datos_entrada = [0] * Num_lineas
    
    for i in range(Num_lineas):   # me controla las filas del array
        
        datos_entrada[i] = linea[i].split("\t")
        
    archivo.close()
    

matriz_resumen = [[0]*3] * Num_lineas    
    
for i in range(Num_lineas):
    
    matriz_resumen[i][0]=datos_entrada[i][2]
    matriz_resumen[i][1]=datos_entrada[i][3]
    matriz_resumen[i][2]=datos_entrada[i][9]
    
print(matriz_resumen)

>>>
[['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n'], ['U06 MIN', '4.285', '-3.241\n']]................
```

Todos los elementos tienen el mismo valor.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: readlines es una pésima idea; cargas TODO el archivo en memoria; un archivo muy grande hará que falle tu programa.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al modificar elementos en sublistas, todas terminan con el mismo contenido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105431/error-al-modificar-elementos-en-sublistas-todas-terminan-con-el-mismo-contenido)

Comment: No multipliques listas de listas. Eso siempre traera comportamientos no deseados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la definición de `matriz_resumen`.
No es una lista con `Num_lineas` listas de 3 elementos:
es una lista con `Num_lineas` copias de la misma lista de 3 elementos.
Para crear una lista cuyos elementos sean listas independientes debes hacerlo así:

```py
matriz_resumen = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(Num_lineas)]
```